# User will enter: 1.His/her DOB. 2.Present day date . You need to calculate and let the user know how many days that person survived in this world

Tags: python

Design an application where user will input two dates.

1. His/her date of birth in DD/MM/YY format.
2. Current (Present day) date in DD/MM/YY format.
   You have to calculate and let the user know how many days that person survived in this world.

i tried to make the code but my output days are coming wrong. Please help me in this.

Comment: If you provide your code, someone should be able to explain where it is going wrong.

Comment: code is long cant post here.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem - it would only take a few lines to do this calculation.